# Get the ID of selected value of BootstrapCSS dropdown menu returns always the first option

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I use BootstrapCSS and create a dropdown menu like this:

```
<div class="btn-group btn-group-sm">
      <div class="dropdown">
         <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" id="modal-button-operators" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" data-target="#">Operator
          <span class="caret"></span></button>
             <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-operators" id="operator_list" style="height: auto; max-height: 200px; overflow-x: hidden;">
                  <li><a href="#" id="=">=</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#" id="&lt;&gt;">&lt;&gt;</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#" id="&gt;">&gt;</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#" id="&lt;">&lt;</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#" id="&gt;=">&gt;=</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#" id="&lt;=">&lt;=</a></li>
                  <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                  <li><a href="#" id=" LIKE ">LIKE</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#" id=" BETWEEN ">BETWEEN</a></li>
               </ul>
 </div>
</div>

<div class="input-group-btn" id="button_query">
   <a href="#" id= 'query_part' class="btn btn-primary btn-mg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" title="Help" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></a>
</div>
```

Later, on button click, I want to get the ID of the selected value and store it in a variable. This is what I do:

```
$(document.body).on("click", "#button_query",function(e) {

        operator_list = $("#operator_list li a").attr('id');

 });
```

But this always gives me the ID of the first option of the dropdown list.
How can I get the ID of the selected value in dropdown menu?

Comment: There is no `#button_query` in your HTML example.

Comment: Thanks. I edited. I have forgotten to include it in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could consider adding a CSS class when a particular element was clicked that could be used to identify it when your button was pressed :

```
// When an element from your list is clicked, set it as "selected"
$("#operator_list li:not(.divider)").click(function(){
        // Ensure only the current one is selected
        $("#operator_list li:not(.divider)").removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
});
```

and then access the selected one through :

```
// Find the selected element and grab its id attribute
operator_list = $("#operator_list li.selected a").attr('id');
```

**Example**

You can [see a working example of this here](http://jsbin.com/satazo/1/edit?html,output) and demonstrated below :

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. This works. Although I have problems understanding they syntax you use. Can you please tell me what's the meaning of: .not(.divider)?

Comment: `li:not(.divider)` would only target `<li>` elements within your list that explicitly didn't have the `divider` class, as you really don't want the user to select that.